# Piping to File Utility

Tags: linux, file, io

I am being sent the bytes of thousands files over an interface, and my app must maintain statistics regarding the counts of various files types which it observes *(text, HTML, binary, compressed, etc.)*. I have been using the `subprocess` module to run the `file` utility. However, as the scale has increased, I am having performance issues due to the IO time needed to write and read the bytes to the disk.

I would like to pipe the bytes directly to `file` to avoid the IO penalty. I have seen this before with `grep` such as `ls -l | grep html`. However, I can't get `echo "Hello, world" | file` to work.

Comment: `echo foo | file -`. The dash stands for `stdin`.

Comment: Awesome! @Roadowl, can you pose this as an answer, so I can mark it as correct and resolve this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo foo | file -`

The dash stands for stdin.